# Cannot initialize XML Serializer in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

```
[Serializable]
public class appData
{
    public string DataFile { get; set; }
    public string LogFile { get; set; }
    public string UploadURL { get; set; }
    public string RssURL { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rss.Items> RssFeed = new Collection<Rss.Items>();
}
public class Rss
{
    [Serializable]
    public struct Items
    {
        public string GUID;
        public DateTime Date;
        public string Title;
        public string Description;
        public string Link;
    }
}

internal static appData appData;
private static XmlSerializer xml;
static void Main()
{
    xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(appData));
}
```

when I run this in the VS 2010 debugger it throws the error `There was an error reflecting type 'FOL.appData'.` yes, my code does have more, but this is the basic parts. These are all within the same assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces can't be serialized - you'll need to change this:

```
public ICollection<Rss.Items> RssFeed = new Collection<Rss.Items>();
```

to this:

```
public Collection<Rss.Items> RssFeed = new Collection<Rss.Items>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the inner exception that you are getting. It will tell you which field/property it is having trouble serializing.

You can exclude fields/properties from xml serialization by decorating them with the **[XmlIgnore()]** attribute.

I don't think that XmlSerializer uses the **[Serializable]** attribute, so I doubt that is the problem.

**Note :**
All to-be serialized classes must have a parameterless constructor and Interfaces can't be serialized as a result.